# Objective C, How to delete string character set?

Tags: objective-c

I download strings from a web server and it contains special characters such as /n /p and so on. What is the best way to get rid of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a list of characters that need stripping?
or you could use

```
[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
Str=[Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""];
if you have selected special characters use Array of special characters and then will also work.

Comment: I know the underlying concepts are usually the same, but we are talking about different languages here. Objective-C is not C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought your best bet would be to use one of the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) methods such as `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` (replacing the characters in question with an empty string) or `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`.